How to set the config paths in Fiddler
I want to call Fiddler from an automation script, and store data in a specific location on the C drive. The default location is specified below. I can override this by changing CONFIG.GetPath("Captures") to something like c:\FiddlerData\Captures\ in the below script.
But how do I change the CONFIG paths themselves? I can't find any way to do that. Do I need to update the registry?
case "dump":
            UI.actSelectAll();
            UI.actSaveSessionsToZip(CONFIG.GetPath("Captures") + "dump.saz");
            UI.actRemoveAllSessions();
            FiddlerObject.StatusText = "Dumped all sessions to " + CONFIG.GetPath("Captures") + "dump.saz";
            return true;


Setting a path is not documented and code of CONFIG.GetPath is heavily obfuscated. I have not seen any registry requests when using this function. Therefore it is unknown where it reads the config.
But as you have the power of Dot.Net in FiddlerScript you can simply write your own config path, e.g. use an existing ENV variable:
UI.actSaveSessionsToZip(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("someenvvar") + "dump.saz");

Or use the Dot.Net functions to read a registry key or a config file if you prefer that.
